# How to write characters backward?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I have written my name in assembly language and I wanted to print it backward. I have no idea how to write it backward.

Here is my code which i need to print it backward.

```
TITLE this is a a-to-z program      (backchar.asm)
; Penpa Gyaltsen

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
space byte ' ',0
myname byte "Penpa Gyaltsen",0
copyofname byte lengthof myname dup(?)

.code
main PROC
        mov eax,0
    mov ecx,lengthof myname
    mov esi,0

backloop:

    mov al,myname[esi]
    mov copyofname[esi],al
    call writechar
    mov edx,offset space
    call writestring
    inc esi
loop backloop;

    call crlf
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What did you try? Since `esi` is used to index the string, you could start it at the end and decrement it instead of starting at 0 and incrementing.

Comment: mov al,myname[esi]
    mov copyofname[esi],al
    call writechar
    mov edx,offset space
    call writestring
    dec esi

Comment: Since this looks like homework, you probably won't get a complete answer. "Enter code here" doesn't work on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yea I know but if you give me little more hint than I can try it. I am trying this first time. Pls give me more hint.

Comment: This is not a debugging service, nor a code-writing service. Furthermore, I doubt if anybody still uses `Irvine32.inc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
TITLE this is a a-to-z program      (backchar.asm)
; Penpa Gyaltsen

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
space byte ' ',0
myname byte "Penpa Gyaltsen",0

.code
main PROC
        mov eax,0
        mov ecx,lengthof myname
        mov esi,lengthof myname
        mov edi,0

backloop:

    mov al,myname[esi]
    call writechar
    mov edx,offset space
    call writestring
    dec esi
loop backloop;

    call crlf
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

i got answer but it missed character "P"

print out like: nestlayg apne

Comment: That's because `lengthof myname` is 15, not 14 - it includes the terminating null character. Remove the final zero from the `myname` string. You're not using it to detect the end of string anyway.

Comment: i have to dec esi before the loop and inside the loop. final zero makes no difference anyway thanks.